# Fixed update menus button in plotly

Tags: plotly

Is there a way to fixe the button to a certain coordinates? When I resized the window in my flask app, the plot change size and my buttons they overlap.

I’ve look at all the arguments possible in the update menus. The X and Y arguments are relative to the plot and yield the current problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.